In VSTO C# development of a Word add-in, Word automatically generates a DLL copy
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            MessageBox.Show(path);
        }

I developed a very simple Word add-in using C#. It only shows a MessageBox with the current DLL's path. I deployed the DLL file on the D drive, but the path I get is a DLL file located under 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3'. Word automatically generates a DLL copy when running my add-in. Why is this happening?
I read the article 'Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce' on Microsoft's website and installed the PFX certificate in the correct location. The effect was evident, as users no longer need to decide how to trust the solution. However, a DLL copy is still being generated.
So, how can I prevent the generation of a DLL copy?
Thank you.

Presumably you can't. That's an effect of the underlying App Domain Feature. You could have multiple VSTO Addins running at the same time and they might share the same assemblies but for proper handling (esp. unloading) they are shadow copied. The VSTO docu has multiple entries/mentionings about App Domains and Shadow Copying. But its not in a way centralized that i could link the relevant one.
